# Bootstrap 3 container change in IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

i have created an template for joomla with the bootstrap 3. my website is only local at the moment. it works all perfect in ff and chrome. but when i have a look at my website in IE (9) it seems like the container changed to fluid. the full website looks horrible.
Have anybody the same problem?

Dont know what i have to copy from my code, that help to find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser is likely rendering the page using ie7 standards, to change this you can goto settings > F12 developer options and change the document mode to ie9.

You can stop IE from doing this by going to Tools > Compatibility View Settings and disable the checkbox 'Display intranet sites in compatability view'

Answer (score 0):

I believe Bootstrap 3 is fluid by default (only fluid, even)?

But without some sample code, I'm unable to advise further.

Btw, I assume you've read http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro thoroughly?

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have a div class=container around all.
then i have only rows like this for example:
<?php if ($this->countModules('bannerovertop')) : ?>
     <div class="row banner">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-1 bannerovertop">
   <jdoc:include type="modules" name="bannerovertop" /> 
    </div>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>

in ff & chrome it all works fine. so the default shouldnt be the problme cause i have an container defined-